# Force/Limit the post/page slug to accept only url friendly characters

Tags: permalinks, slug

Is there a way to overwrite WP slug validation function to only accept basic characters ([A-Z0-9-]) as I want to avoid the long encoded permlink.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For now I used the `sanitize_title` filter, and removed all unwanted characters, which forces my users to use only `[a-z0-9-]` as a valid input for titles.

```
## Allow only [a-z0-9-] in the slug
function my_clear_title($title) {

    $pattern = '/[^a-z_0-9- ]/i';
    $replace_with = '';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replace_with, $title);
}
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'my_clear_title', 3, 1);
```

- I had to use a higher priority (3) to make sure my filter will run before wordpress builtin  filters.

Comment: IIRC `sanitize_title` has a context parameter which you might want to check to make sure you are not sanitizing things that are not slugs in this way.

Comment: Thanks @MarkKaplun for the input, I looked on the documentations and the source for this function, the `context` parameter is more like a "when" and not "what" parameter and it default to `save`. from my testing it looks like it works for permalinks as well on names for tags and category's (which is great)

Comment: In one of the plugin I wrote I use a context of my own to avoid this type of sanitation..... You really should check the context

Comment: you mean to explicitly check that the context is on save ? and only then apply my filter ?